# Metor JS installation fails in ubuntu

Tags: javascript, ubuntu, curl, meteor

curl (18) transfer closed "some bytes" remaining. Problem in ubuntu 14.04
I followed many tutorials available but still the problem exists.
Please help Me to solve this problem.

Comment: please add detail error from your terminal. I am work with Ubuntu 16.04 all work fine.

Comment: It might be network issue. Please try running the command again.

Answer (score -1):

That's the issue with my ubuntu installation. I just reinstall my ubuntu.
Now the problem is solved.